# getting testing case failure while making the network up in first-network of fabric-samples in google cloud

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

```
===================== Chaincode Instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' is successful =====================  Querying chaincode on peer0.org1... 

CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt 

CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP 

CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock 

CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true 

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ID=cli CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO 

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 

===================== Querying on peer0.org1 on channel 'mychannel'... =====================  Attempting to Query peer0.org1 ...3 secs + 

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}' + res=0 + set +x 100 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Query result on peer0.org1 is INVALID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ================== ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

you can see my cli env and logs on querying my channel. It's giving ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ================== ERROR !!!! Test failed

Answer (score 0):

Try following lines:

```
$./byfn.sh down
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
```

Then restart the Docker, after that try this:

```
$./byfn.sh generate
$./byfn.sh up
```